# How to prevent Scale from changing Sizes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

In a previous post I asked about how to debug a scale issue: [Debugging Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621184/how-to-debug-a-scale-issue/40621954?noredirect=1#comment68478295_40621954)

After fixing the problem there seems to be another issue, which I don't understand.  I am trying to delete my list of buttons and populate a new list  of buttons (refresh).

I broke out the functions to delete the buttons and then to add them back.  I am using the same script that sets up the original buttons, `MakeAllButtons`.

This is what it looks like when I populate the list of buttons
[image]

When I remove the list of buttons and add back the list of buttons it looks like this.  A scale reduction to .3.

[image]

If I add another list  of buttons (just clicking `Add` a second time) it looks like this:
[image]

The scale for the list of buttons is back to where its suppose to be.

ADD Button Code:

```
public void MakeAllButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positionList.Count; i++)
        {

            Position position = positionList[i];
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PositionUnlocked" + i, position.unlocked); //sets if the item is unlocked

            GameObject newButton = buttonObjectPool.GetObject();
            newButton.transform.SetParent(positionPanel, false); //this was the problem originally

            ButtonDetails buttonDetails = newButton.GetComponent<ButtonDetails>();
            buttonDetails.SetupPosition(position, this);
        }
}
```

REMOVE BUTTON CODE

```
public void RemoveButtons()
{
    while (positionPanel.childCount > 0)
    {
        GameObject toRemove = positionPanel.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        buttonObjectPool.ReturnObject(toRemove);
    }
}
```

After the `newButton` is created, somehow the `newButton.localScale` is being set to .3, but only for the first run through of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when I removed the object it was storing the scale from the previous loading.

So I forced the new object to have the scale I want and it fixed the problem.

```
        GameObject newButton = buttonObjectPool.GetObject();
        newButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        newButton.transform.SetParent(positionPanel, false);
```